# How to achieve the indentation/spacing in this document?

Tags: spacing, indentation

I have been trying for some hours to achieve the kind of arrangement of this document.

http://home.uchicago.edu/klecha/klecha_cv.pdf

For instance, it seems like it has two columns, one with dates etc. and the other with publications, etc. but the two are kept at a fixed distance always. What would be a code to achieve such an arrangement, so that the second column of each section begins at the same point?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Just use a table/several tables with two columns, set to absolute width with `p` columntype, `longtable`should work as well. The `booktabs` package might come handy to have the lines in a nice way.

Comment: You can find similar (not identical) formats in [LaTeX Templates](http://www.latextemplates.com/cat/curricula-vitae). You can download .tex files and look how they did it. Some of them are constructed with `tabularx` environments as Uwe suggested.

Comment: Thank you all very much for your help! I apologize for not being sufficiently clear on my question!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create it yourself.

Here is a MWE to start with:

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \textbf{Your name}

  \emph{June 2013}
\end{center}

Department of Linguistics \hfill  me@mydomain.com

University of Nowhere \hfill \url{http://www.mydomain.com}

1010 E. 59th St., Chicago, IL, 60637 \hfill  810-111-9999

\hrulefill\vspace*{\baselineskip}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}p{5cm}X@{}}
\textbf{Education}    & \\
2007--2013 (expected) & PhD Program in Linguistics, University of Chicago\newline
                        \emph{Dissertation: Scalarity and Modality} (in progress)\newline
                        \emph{Chair:} Prof. Chris Kennedy \\
2012                  &  Visiting Scholar, University of Massachusetts, Amherst\newline
                        \emph{Sponsor:} Prof. Angelika Kratzer
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Yes! This is exactly it! Thank you very much, I was trying for hours to use some sort of table but failed!

Comment: @OrestXherija You're welcome. :-)